# sorl-thumbnail: random name in Thumbnail field

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I want to use `str(uuid.uuid4())` instead of the name uploaded.

I have this model:

```
class foo(models.Model):
   pic  = ThumbnailField(upload_to='pics', size=(200, 200))
```

I am uploading `hello_world.jpg` and I should save these named versions should be saved for example in `4ba9b397-da69-4307-9bce-e92887e84d2f.jpg`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this in your view:

```
myfile = request.FILES['file']
foo_model = foo()
foo_model.pic.save("%s.jpg" % str(uuid.uuid4()), myfile, save=True)
```